# Avoid removing trailing slash at the end of the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

Current:

> domain.com/ (goes to) => domain.com/th
>
> domain.com/th/ => domain.com/th
>
> domain.com/en/ => domain.com/en

Expectation:

> domain.com/ => domain.com/th/
>
> domain.com/th/ => domain.com/th/
>
> domain.com/en/ => domain.com/en/

I want a trailing slash for these URLs.

Configuration:

```
i18n: {
    locales: ['th', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'th',
    localeDetection: false,
    pages: {
        '*': ['common']
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple config you can add to your next.config file, just explicitly set the `trailingSlash` value to `true`

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to avoid trailing slash for above URLs only. ⚡️

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, these locales will be appended to all pages on the site (pages: {'*'}), so it'll only append to the locales unless I'm missing something. Do you mean that you want it to go to 'domain.com/th/', but 'domain.com/subdomain/th'? If it's just about adding it after these specific locales I imagine explicitly naming them 'th/' might help, but again that should just achieve the same thing as the answer above since they're appended to all subdomains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Exactly! we don’t want `/` to be added to all the pages. but only on the above pages. ⚡️

Comment: @BhavinRana If you want to add the trailing slash only on specific paths, then I'm afraid you'd have to setup a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in your Next.js app, to have full control over it.

Answer (score 0):

I think nowadays: `skipTrailingSlashRedirect` can be used: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#advanced-middleware-flags